# How is it possible to keep values still in their fields after submit?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

```
   <form action='checks.php' method='POST'>
    <div class ="bookinform">
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>Name of Driver *</td>
            <td>
               <input type='Text' id="driver_name" name='driver_name' required autocomplete="off" size='7' maxlength='25' style='width:400px;font-family:Century Gothic' value = "">
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Vehicle Reg *</td>
            <td>
               <input type='Text' id="Vehicle_Reg" name='Vehicle_Reg' required autocomplete="off" size='7' maxlength='15' style='width:400px;font-family:Century Gothic; text-transform:uppercase;' value = "">
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td valign='top'>Haulier *</td>
            <td valign='top'>
              <input type='Text' id="query" name='haulier' style='width:400px; font-family:Century Gothic; text-transform:uppercase;' value = "">

         <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>

         </table>

     <input type='submit' name='FORM' value="Book-in Piece/s" style='width:100%;font-family:Century Gothic; margin-top:10px; color:#2EFE2E;'>
   </form>
```

How can I keep the values entered into `Name of drive`, `Vehicle reg` and `Haulier` to stay there after the submit button has been pressed? I want this so they don't have to be continuously entered. My form already as an action going else where so I can use `$_POST` on this page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need to do is to check to see if the value for that input has already been `POST`ed and, if it has, to `echo` that value.

To do this, in the `val` attribute, add:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST["name_of_input"])) echo $_POST["name_of_input"]; ?>
```

...or using ternary operators:

```
<?php echo(isset($_POST["name_of_input"]) ? $_POST["name_of_input"] : ""); ?>
```

It is also good practice to output using `htmlspecialchars()` as some `POST` content might contain invalid HTML.

---

**Full example**

```
<input type='Text'
    id="driver_name"
    name='driver_name'
    required
    autocomplete="off"
    size='7'
    maxlength='25'
    style='width:400px;font-family:Century Gothic'
    value="<?php echo (isset($_POST["driver_name"]) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST["driver_name"]) : ""); ?>">
```

Comment: generally speaking, you should always output via `htmlspecialchars()` when filling in form values, in case the data contains html metachars, e.g. `value="John "The Hammer" Doe"` isn't exactly valid html...

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the value after submit by this way:

```
<input type='Text' id="driver_name" name='driver_name' required autocomplete="off" size='7' maxlength='25' style='width:400px;font-family:Century Gothic' value = "<?php echo isset($_POST['driver_name']) ? $_POST['driver_name'] : NULL ?>">
```